# Ruby on Rails - application not working properly when run in domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with my Ruby on Rails application.

When I run the app as `rails s -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000` it runs as expected. If I run `lsof -wni tcp:3000` (in another terminal) I get:

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    13265 tamer   14u  IPv4 1686252872      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci (LISTEN)
```

However, if I run the app as `rails s -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -d` I don't get complete responses in browser and if I run `lsof -wni tcp:3000` I get :

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    12700 tamer   14u  IPv4 1686177850      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci (LISTEN)
ruby    12700 tamer   19u  IPv4 1686181848      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27643 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   25u  IPv4 1686181409      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27623 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   26u  IPv4 1686181417      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27625 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   27u  IPv4 1686181425      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27627 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   28u  IPv4 1686181458      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27629 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   29u  IPv4 1686181459      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27631 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   30u  IPv4 1686181460      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27633 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   31u  IPv4 1686181461      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27635 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   32u  IPv4 1686182162      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27651 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   33u  IPv4 1686181463      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27639 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   34u  IPv4 1686181465      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27641 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   35u  IPv4 1686181849      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27645 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   36u  IPv4 1686181851      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27647 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   37u  IPv4 1686181852      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27649 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   38u  IPv4 1686182163      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27653 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   39u  IPv4 1686182177      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27657 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   40u  IPv4 1686182178      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27659 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   41u  IPv4 1686182179      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27661 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   42u  IPv4 1686182180      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27665 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   43u  IPv4 1686182181      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27667 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   44u  IPv4 1686182182      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27669 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   45u  IPv4 1686182183      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27671 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   46u  IPv4 1686182184      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27673 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   47u  IPv4 1686182185      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27675 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   48u  IPv4 1686182186      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27677 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   49u  IPv4 1686182187      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27679 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby    12700 tamer   50u  IPv4 1686182188      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci->127.0.0.1:27681 (ESTABLISHED)
```

What is the cause of this issue and how to fix it

I'm using `ruby 2.5.0p0` and `Rails 5.1.5`. The server OS is `CentOS 7`.

***UPDATE2***

I get the same problem if I run `rails s -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000` (works as expected, so far) and then `ctrl+z` (starts the strange behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify database path to "-d" option? And I think ctrl+z doesn't kill the process and it can be able to run on background. Try to specify db adapter name (mysql, oracle etc.) and try again

Comment: As for the database, it is pre configured in the application. Moreover, -d here stands for "domain" not "database". It is used to run the application in domain (background).
As for ctrl+z . Yes it runs the process in background. This is exactly what I was trying to do, to run the process in the background.